# Python : Extract HTML content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to get "Data to be extracted" content by extracting the following html, using BeautifulSoup or any library

```
<div>
    <ul class="main class">
      <li>
        <p class="class_label">User Name</p>
        <p>"Data to be extracted"</p>
      </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly multiple options. For starters, you can find the `p` element with `class="class_label"` and get the [next `p` sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <ul class="main class">
      <li>
        <p class="class_label">User Name</p>
        <p>"Data to be extracted"</p>
      </li>
 </ul>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('p', class_='class_label').find_next_sibling('p').text
```

Or, using a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div ul.main li p.class_label + p')[0].text
```

Or, relying on the `User Name` text:

```
soup.find(text='User Name').parent.find_next_sibling('p').text
```

Or, relying on the `p` element's position inside the `li` tag:

```
soup.select('div ul.main li p')[1].text
```